# oblique thumbnail or picture

Tags: javascript, css

What is the best way to achieve the result on [this page](http://www.arnaudbeelen.be/)

In other words; how do you get the pictures to look like this with a css or javascript solution?

Thanks, Richard

Comment: Those images are designed in that shape: http://www.arnaudbeelen.be/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/logo2012.jpg - but could be done by using image masks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

crop image with transparent background like the above link website using

http://www.arnaudbeelen.be/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/voeux2012.jpg

Comment: I thought there maybe was a css trick to do that, where you can give different heights to the left and right side

Comment: It is possible with css but not crossbrowser - it is much more simple to do it like this if you don't really have to have it all dynamic.

Comment: yes its possible only in css3 but its not browser's compatible, specially in IE.

Comment: @jassi9911 - could be also done in IE - you just need an extra div in your markup - check my answer.

Comment: @easwee ok, that's fine but it will take extra coding and image space so why we can do this just simple put the effort on cropping image on some image editor software and upload it, i think so.

Comment: also there is no actual height and width of a particular image some images are big in size

Comment: Yes - but it is atleast dynamic to a certain point - if your client has no image editing skills and just wants the solution to work out of the box you will have to make it dynamic - he won't call you each time he needs an image edited and pay you except you are willing to do it for free (which would be dumb).

Answer (score 0):

With css only (webkit browsers only - would need to dig in if it is possible on other browsers but i doubt it):

http://jsfiddle.net/536S8/

```
<div class="image-thumbnail">
    <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

.image-thumbnail {
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
    -webkit-mask-image: url('mymaskimage.png');
    -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-position:0 0;
}
```

and another approach by having a mask layer over your image (requires extra mask div - your mask image has to be same color as the background):

http://jsfiddle.net/PCfWa/

```
<div class="image-thumbnail">
    <div class="image-mask"></div>
    <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

.image-thumbnail {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.image-mask {
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;
    height:250px;        
    z-index:2;  
    background:url(mymask.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create image mask with some areas filled in with background color and transparent visible areas after that just overlay it on top of original image (using absolute positioning and `z-index`). If you have some text that needs to be selectable/clickable put that in a new element on top of the mask using same techniques as for the mask but with bigger `z-index` value.